# How to set a variable to fulfill a condition outside a for loop cycle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, if-statement, cycle

problem:

I created a search form where the user is asked to insert a string into an input form. The string is the name of the city and if it matches one of the 50 cities I have included into a JSON file some function is called.
We may have three conditions:

1)  The input form is left empty ------>  an error log appears.

2)  The input form is not empty and the string matches one of the 50 strings in the JSON file ------>  a table is displayed.

3)  The input form is not empty but the string doesn’t match any of the 50 strings in the JSON file ------>  a modal window is displayed

My problem is how and where to write the command:

```
$(‘#Modal#).show()
```

In other terms, how and where should I show the modal window whenever the city inserted doesn’t match with any of those included in my JSON file?

I have a `cycle for`: here the values of the strings in the JSON file are being checked; I wouldn’t put the command into there, otherwise the modal  will be called 49 times: since I have 50 cities, one of them matches the string inserted in the input form but the other 49 don't.

I suppose I should create a new variable with a function outside the `for loop` cycle, setting the condition : "the string matches one and only one of the strings in the JSON file"; then the condition may be true inside the for loop (and then I display the table), whereas it's false outside the for loop (i.e. "if the number of cities found is 0" and then I show the modal window).

The code I wrote so far is the following:

```
function validateCitta() {
  let text = $('#inlineFormInputCitta').val();
  if (text === "") {
    $("#errorLog").show();
  } else {
    $("#errorLog").hide();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent($("#inlineFormInputCity").val()) + "&format=geocodejson",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
          let typeCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.type;
          if (typeCity === "city") {
            let nameCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.name;
            for (let i = 0; i < json.tappe.length; i++) {
              let tappa = json.tappe[i];
              let city = json.tappe[i].city;
              if (city === nameCity) {
                console.log("JSON file has been activated");
                $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + tappa.name + "</td><td>" + tappa.state + "</td><td>" + tappa.region + "</td><td>" + tappa.city + "</td></tr>");
                $("#tabella").show();
              };
            };
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
};
```

How may I set the new variable to fulfill the third 3) condition above?
OR ALTERNATIVELY, would you have any other suggestion to show the modal window if the condition (3) is fulfilled?

- - - -E D I T E D - - - -

I edited the snippet as in the following:

```
function validateCitta() {    

    let text = $('#inlineFormInputCitta').val(); 
    var check = false;    
    if (text === "") {    
        $("#errorLog").show();    
    } else {    
        $("#errorLog").hide(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val()) + "&format=geocodejson",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {    
                for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
                    let typeCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.type;    
                    if (typeCity === "city") {    
                        let nameCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.name;        
                        for (let i = 0; i < json.tappe.length; i++) {    
                            let tappa = json.tappe[i];    
                            let city = json.tappe[i].city;    
                            if (city === nameCity) {    
                                var check = true;  
                                $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + tappa.name + "</td><td>" + tappa.state + "</td><td>" + tappa.region + "</td><td>" + tappa.city + "</td></tr>");    
                                $("#tabella").show(); 
                            }
                            ;
                        }
                        ;   
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        if (check) {
            $('#myModal').show();
        }
    }
};
```

But it doesn't work.
On the other hand, If I write

```
if (!check) {
                $('#myModal').show();
```

the modal is displayed also when the condition 2) is fulfilled...

- - - -E D I T E D   2 - - - -

I wrote the following code. **It works, but** I don't understand completely the role of the boolean flag `check` and the way its value changes inside and outside the for loop:

```
function validateCitta() {        
    let text = $('#inlineFormInputCitta').val();

    if (text === "") {            
        $("#errorLog").show();
    }   //condition 1: no strings, no problem

    else {                      
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val()) + "&format=geocodejson",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                var check = false;     //I set the flag variable outside the cycle

                for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
                    let typeCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.type;
                    if (typeCity === "city") {
                        let nameCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.name;
                        for (let i = 0; i < json.tappe.length; i++) {
                            let tappa = json.tappe[i];
                            let city = json.tappe[i].city;
                            if (city === nameCity) {

                                check = true;    
               //conditon 3 is fullfilled: strings matches


                                $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + tappa.name + "</td><td>" + tappa.state + "</td><td>" + tappa.region + "</td><td>" + tappa.city + "</td></tr>");
                                $("#tabella").show();                                    
                            }
                                ;
                        }
                            ;
                    }
                }    
                if (!check) {   //does !check means that the value of 'check' is opposite to the one set at the beginning?
                    $('#myModal').show();                    }
            }
        })            
    }    
};
```

Does `var check = false` means that everything is written after it (the for loop in this case) is false?

Does `!check` means that `var check = false` isn't true, i.e. `check === true`?
If so, why should I specify `check = true` inside the for loop? Isn't `check = true` the same as `!check`? In other terms, what is the `check` telling me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag that tells if a city was found.

In example :

```
if (typeCity === "city") {
    let nameCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.name;
    let IsCityFound = false; // <------------------------------- not found by default
    for (let i = 0; i < json.tappe.length; i++) {
        let tappa = json.tappe[i];
        let city = json.tappe[i].city;
        if (city === nameCity) {
            IsCityFound = true; // <---------------------------- Now found
            console.log("JSON file has been activated");
            $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + tappa.name + "</td><td>" + tappa.state + "</td><td>" + tappa.region + "</td><td>" + tappa.city + "</td></tr>");
            $("#tabella").show();
        }
    }
    if (!IsCityFound) { // <------------------------------------ Was it NOT found ?
        $('#Modal').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering. If I add the ! in the last 'if condition' the modal is always displayed, even when the '(typeCity === "city")' condition is fulfilled. On the contrary, if I omit the '!', it's not displayed at all...

Comment: What does the exclamation mark means in 'if (!IsCityFound)'? in the debugging 'IsCityFound' is given "false" value whether or not I write the '!'

Comment: `!false === true`

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use a boolean variable as a flag and then outside the loop check if the value changed.

```
function validateCitta() {
  let text = $('#inlineFormInputCitta').val();
  let check = false;

  if (text === "") {
    $("#errorLog").show();
  } else {
    $("#errorLog").hide();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent($("#inlineFormInputCity").val()) + "&format=geocodejson",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
          let typeCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.type;
          if (typeCity === "city") {
            let nameCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.name;
            for (let i = 0; i < json.tappe.length; i++) {
              let tappa = json.tappe[i];
              let city = json.tappe[i].city;
              if (city === nameCity) {
                check = true;
              };
            };
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
  //check if you need to display the modal

  if (check)
  {
  console.log("JSON file has been activated");
  $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + tappa.name + "</td><td>" + tappa.state + "</td><td>" + tappa.region + "</td><td>" + tappa.city + "</td></tr>");
  $("#tabella").show();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I want to display the modal shouldn't I use the command '$(‘#Modal#).show()'? Why did you put the lines of codes which follow the 'if (check)' outside the 'for loop'?